# Are you able to buffer labels to prevent other labels within the buffer area?

Tags: qgis

I saw a post that talks about label offsets, but that was in 1.7. I did some internet research with no success. Is there a way to apply a buffer area so that labels from another layer are not placed in the buffer area? Otherwise the only option that I can think of is actually moving all labels that are in conflict manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as far as I know. It's a rather rare requirement for a label placement algorithm.

It would probably be fastest to rearrange the labels in post processing (Inkscape or other tool).

Comment: Thanks, I think ArcGIS has something similar. What would your process be on this. Save each layer individually as a svg? I have tried the whole map project as an svg with little success.

Answer (score 0):

Using the label placement tools in QGIS will be repeatable.